# .Net Framework Config File

Tags: .net, app-config

i have a question about configuration loading. I have an App that loads a .net dll implementing a certain interface, our website has a config indicating where that DLL is located, and searches the location, loads the dll and invokes the interface.
So far, so good, but the interface implementation connects to a WS and requires a configuration file containing web service endpoints, which it seems not to find. Im suspecting the runtime is not searching it. Its named file.dll.config and located in the same folder.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLL assemblies have no (automatically considered) configuration files. You need to put the relevant configuration in the `.exe.config` of the application that uses the code from the DLL.

The DLL *could* load / consider it's own configuration file (say `foo.dll.config`) but then would have to explicitly load it using [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.2) and specifying the path to the respective confiugration file explicitly. Also, all code that wants to use entries from that configuration file would have to use `Configuration`-instance returned by that call. Simply using the `static` version `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String)` wouldn't work, as that would only consider the `.exe.config`.